# How do I make Webpack exit with an error when jshint emits warnings?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, jshint, webpack

Using [jshint-loader](https://github.com/webpack/jshint-loader) with [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), how do I make the `webpack` command fail when JSHint emits warnings?

The context being that I wish to fail the CI build if linting detects issues.

Currently, I've simply configured Webpack to run jshint-loader on preload of JS files:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'jshint-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

First, jshint-loader must be configured to fail in case issues are found (`failOnHint: true`), optionally one can also choose to emit warnings as Webpack errors (`emitErrors: true`).

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'jshint-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  jshint: {
    emitErrors: true,
    failOnHint: true,
  },
};
```

Second, Webpack must be told to fail hard, by supplying the `--bail` option: `webpack --bail`.

## Update:

`webpack --bail` still doesn't emit a non-zero exit code, argh.

Comment: Hm, how come webpack complains that '"jshint" is not allowed' when I add a jshint option to the config?

Comment: Ah, because of webpack validator, I needed to add a custom rule to the validator schema. https://github.com/js-dxtools/webpack-validator#schema

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but this solution doesn't help. I am still getting warnings and "module build failed", but it still results in succesful code 0.

Comment: @SergejsRižovs Back then I eventually realized that `webpack --bail` returns zero even in the case of failure (see the Update bit at the end of the answer). I don't know how it is now, as I haven't tested it for some time.